# How to get a string from strings.xml by adding int to the name

Tags: java, android, settext, r.java-file

```
private int info = 1;

public void nextStep(View view)
{    
    TextView textInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textInfo);
    textInfo.setText(R.string.info1);
    info++;
}
```

When one button is clicked, method `nextStep` is called. And every time a button clicked, I want to show different info, first time it's `info1` string, next time it's `info2` string and etc. from `strings.xml`. I would like to do something like that:

```
private int info = 1;

public void nextStep(View view)
{    
    TextView textInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textInfo);
    textInfo.setText(R.string.info + info);
    info++;
}
```

Of course, it's not possible. What should I do? I really don't want to write a big if/else or switch statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Of course, it's not possible.

Actually, it is. You can use `getIdentifier` to do this:

```
private int info = 1;
public void nextStep(View view)
{    
    TextView textInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textInfo);
    int myStrId = textInfo.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("info"+info, "string", textInfo.getContext().getPackageName());
    textInfo.setText(myStrId);
    info++;
}
```

[`getIdentifer()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is a way to fetch resource IDs that are stored in `R` if you don't know the exact name. While it isn't the most efficient method in the world, it suffices in situations where referencing `R` (such as your situation) is not possible.

The method returns the same ID that `R` would; that is, `getIdentifier("info1", "id", ...);` is the same as `R.id.info1`, since `R` is just a compiled version of it. This method also works in the event that you are unsure if an ID exists (such as from an external library) but need to reference it anyway.

Comment: And that is just awesome, wow. But maybe you could explain this answer a little bit?

Comment: There, I amended my post with a bit of explanation as well as a link to the documentation on it. Hope that's a bit more helpful! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of String or better a `List<String>` such as an `ArrayList<String>` and fill it with the Strings from the XML. Then you can use the `get(int index)` method to get the ith String in the list.

If you are using JAXB to unmarshall your XML, you can have it set up to create your List for you without much fuss.

Comment: So, on `onCreate` method, I should call a new methods, let's say, `fillList()` and do something like this: `infoArrayList.add(R.string.info1); infoArrayList.add(R.string.info2); ex.infoArrayList(R.string.info3);` and etc.? I made it, it works, but are you sure it's the easiest/best solution? Because everytime I add new info, I also need to add it to arraylist. Thank you.

Comment: @hey: No, I don't recommend anything as clunky as that, but rather would use JAXB to automatically create your list for you from your XML file. I'm not familiar with Android programming, but I do believe that JAXB, which is part of core Java, is available for you to use.